# Microsoft Kinect - openNI Hand Generator issue

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

I am trying to use a kinect device in order to detect the palm within a kinect video(.oni video). I am using openNI libraries to develop this type of application.

They have published a manual of the basic features available within the openNI which can be seen [here](http://75.98.78.94/Documentation.aspx).

I have tried to implement the code which they displayed in the hand detection section, however, I don't have any results.

Do you happen to know where can I find a tutorial for a basic hand detection application for kinect through openNI library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with [OpenNI User Guide](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Documentation/OpenNI_UserGuide.pdf) and it was very useful. There is a working example called **"Working with Hand Point"**. If you want more powerful hand recognition you can try *NITE*.  You can have working sample following [this tutorial](http://www.keyboardmods.com/2010/12/howto-kinect-openninite-skeleton.html), it is for Linux, but most part of it will work even for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with :

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Simple-Hand-Tracking-with-MS-Kinect-SDK--WPF